# Efficient method for storing simple regular expressions

Tags: sql, regex, database, data-structures

I have a list of simple regular expressions:

```
ABC.+DE.+FHIJ.+
.+XY.+Z.+AB
.+KLM.+NO.+J.+
QRST.+UV
```

they all have alternating patterns of .+ and some text (I will call "words") repeated some number of times.  A pattern may or may not begin or end in .+.  These regular expression are all mutually exclusive.  When another regex is added I want to remove any other matching regular expressions, and add one regular expression that combines the added one with all of its matches.  For example, adding:

```
.+J.+
```

would match,

```
ABC.+DE.+FHIJ.+
.+KLM.+NO.+J.+
```

and thus, these would be remove and replaced with the added regular expression resulting in:

```
.+J.+ 
.+XY.+Z.+AB
QRST.+UV
```

I need to store these patterns either in some data structure or (preferably) in a database in an efficient manner. I first tried a tree of dictionaries, only to realize that in the case that a regex starts with a .* it has to search the entire tree for the next word, which is order O(2^n).  Unfortunately, (unless I am mistaken) it appears that neither SQLite (which I am using) nor any other relational database that I have used, supports "regular expression" as a data type.  My question is, is there an efficient method for storing and retrieving such simple regular expressions?  If there is no canned method, is there some data structure that would be relatively efficient (say, at worst amortized polynomial time)?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please explain what you are using these regular expressions for as that would make it easier to provide a better answer? In particular when I see the way you are splitting your regular expressions I'm wondering if a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or a [Directed acyclic word graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph) would be a better fit.

From their you may find your answer is as simple as providing better normalization or finding an alternative no SQL db made specifically for your problem area.